# Displaying youtube video in silverlight app using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, silverlight

I'm converting an application from php/js/css over to c#/silverlight for a client.

In the old system, I used a URL & the jquery prettyPhoto plugin to display a youtube video.

In the new system, silverlight cannot play FLV natively.

Does anybody have a process & code for how to get my link from the silverlight app, over to a div in my aspx page hosting the silverlight control (default.aspx), then playing the video?

Cheers,

Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have this Javascript function in your host .aspx page:-

```
  function goAheadAndPlayThatVid(urlOfVid)
  {
      // some code that plays the Vid
  }
```

Now in Silverlight/C# code you can invoke this function with:-

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("goAheadAndPlayThatVid", "urlOfVidHere");
```

Comment: Perfect thanks. Appreciate all your help on SO - both in questions I've asked, and in answers I've found on here.